# A word for a person in an employment role that is petty

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I'm trying to think of a specific word and so far google isn't much help. It describes a type of employment role where the person has quite an impressive sounding title but in actuality the job role itself is rather petty and officious, also 'under worked and over paid' could be used to describe it. If I recall correctly it sounds something like 'Cosine'. Does anyone know which word I'm referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sinecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinecure)

> A sinecure (/ˈsɪnɪkjʊər/ or /ˈsaɪnɪkjʊər/; from Latin sine 'without' and cura 'care') is an office, carrying a salary or otherwise generating income, that requires or involves little or no responsibility, labour, or active service.
> ...
> A sinecure can also be given to an individual whose primary job is in another office, but requires a sinecure title to perform that job. For example, the Government House Leader in Canada is often given a sinecure ministry position so that they may become a member of the Cabinet. Similar examples are the Lord Keeper of the Privy Seal and the Chancellor of the Duchy of Lancaster in the British cabinet. The minister without portfolio is a frequent example of this sinecure, often employed to give cabinet-level positions to enough members of all partners in a coalition government. Other sinecures operate as legal fictions, such as the British office of Crown Steward and Bailiff of the Chiltern Hundreds, used as a legal excuse for resigning from Parliament.

Comment: Thank you, Pete. Spot on.